Crack in foundation (outside only). Severity?
I started redoing my deck and discovered this crack (pic) outside of my home's foundation. The inside shows no signs of cracking and the foundation is covered from any weather. The home was built in 1917 and it is in pretty good shape otherwise. I am seeking advice on how severe this is and any recommendations on getting it fixed by a professional or just DIYing. Thanks in advance

That looks like something you would need an engineer to analyze.  There is little we can do here from a picture. Many variables to consider.
